# Multilingual Linguistic Data

Tags: database, translation, turkish

Oxford University provides an online database (the Oxford English Dictionary API) containing linguistic information (root form, part of speech, etc.) about English words. It provides comparable data for Spanish, Malay, Swahili, Setswana, Northern Sotho, Latvian, Indonesian, Urdu, Zulu, Romanian, Hindi, German, Portuguese, Tamil, and Gujarati.

While this is definitely quite a diverse bunch of languages, it unfortunately does not contain the language I need data for: Turkish. I'm attempting to write a rule-based machine translation program (No, I don't need your rambles about how machine translation will never work), you see, and I really need the data.

My question is: does anyone know of a database of linguistic data that supports Turkish?

(Note: this is my first question, so sorry if I break any rules.)

Comment: You want to find a turkish-wildcard translation database, to use as a bridge with oxford api, matching the 3 languajes?

Comment: What I had meant was something that supported specifically Turkish, but that's a good idea. I should try that.

Comment: I wish this kind of situations were more common in SO. Please try to find something on market.mashape.com there are plenty of free API

Comment: [**gogle's translate api**](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) (which isn't free). Is "free" part of the unstated requirement?